# How to loop through a data table and get the current row/index if the value match with a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable

My WPF application contains a form which when loaded, obtains two variables which contain a PID (**procid**) and a processname (**procname**) of a certain process currently running on the local computer.

I have a data table which contains `netstat -ano` data outputs in each column. Now i will need to compare either (**procid**) or (**procname**) with the associated data contained in the datatable, if both variable matches, store the current index/row number and use that index to get the remote ip address (**remoteIp**) of the associated datarow to be stored as variables.

How would i achieve this?

**Pageone.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class Pageone : Page
    {        
        public Pageone(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }
        private string remoteIp;

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //instantiate the MainWindow and assign it to the 'window' variable    
            var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            string procName = window.proc1;
            int subprocPid = window.proc2;
            string procPID = subprocPid.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(procPID);

            using (Process ns = new Process())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
                    new DataColumn("Protocol"),
                    new DataColumn("Local Address"),
                    new DataColumn("Foreign Address"),
                    new DataColumn("State"),
                    new DataColumn("PID"),
                    new DataColumn("Process Name"),
                });

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netstat.exe", "-ano");
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                ns.StartInfo = psi;
                // Run it, and read the results
                ns.Start();
                using (StreamReader r = ns.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string output = r.ReadToEnd();
                    ns.WaitForExit();

                    //Parse those results into a DataTable, polling the Process info
                    string[] lines = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        string[] elements = line.Split(' ');
                        if (elements.Length < 5) continue;
                        if (elements.Contains("Proto")) continue;

                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        List<string> validElements = new List<string>();

                        //Weed out empty elements.
                        foreach (string element in elements)
                        {
                            //skip blanks
                            if (element.Trim() == "") continue;
                            validElements.Add(element);
                        }

                        foreach (string element in validElements)
                        {
                            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                // fill in the buckets. Note that UDP doesn't have a state
                                if (dr["Protocol"].ToString() == "UDP" && dc.ColumnName == "State") continue;

                                if (dr[dc] == DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                    dr[dc] = element;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        dr["Process Name"] = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(dr["PID"].ToString())).ProcessName;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);                        
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i ++)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

                        ///if cellprocPid and procPID matches, get the current index of the row and
                        ///store it in the remoteIp variable
                        ///

                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(remoteIp);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable has `select` method, where you can pass `fiterexpression` to select rows matching filter condition

```
string expression = "PID= " + procPID.ToString();
var foundRows = table.Select(expression);

// Access rows
for (int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(foundRows[i][0]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried your code but change ```Console.WriteLine(foundRows[i][0]);``` to ```MessageBox.Show(foundRows[i][0].ToString());``` as i am coding a wpf application, but the code seem to "exit" right after ```for (int i = 0; ``` ? not running the messagebox.show line.